# Broadcast to all users in friends list with kopete?

Tags: kde, kopete

in kopete you can right click a group and send a message to the group. It also seems there's a hidden toplevel group that you can move users to. Is it possible to send a message to this toplevel group so that all users in your friends list receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I have found this is not possible, so [I opened a feature request bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=257211) for it.